# How to throw alert if no records for today's date

Tags: c#

When there are no records for a project on this day (no records with the current date in a particular field on my page) I want to throw an alert message.

This is what I tried, but it's not doing the trick:

```
var FirstSampleOfTheDay = (from a in db.SampleNIOSHTotalParticulate
                           where a.ProjectID == ProjectID
                           select a).ToList();

foreach (var fs in FirstSampleOfTheDay)
{
    var SampleDate = fs.SampleDate.ToString().Split("/");
    var SampleDateDay = SampleDate[1];

    if (Int32.Parse(SampleDateDay) == DateTime.Now.Day)
    {
        ViewBag.FirstSample = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this code throw any alert ?

Comment: Is this for a webpage, wpf, winforms, console application?

Comment: What do you mean by "throw an alert" - throw an Exception, perhaps?  Why are you converting a DateTime to a string and then parsing the string back into a DateTime.  Just use `if (fs.Date == DateTime.Today)`.  Or, more simply, put `&& a.Date == DateTime.Today` in your where clause and test the resulting list for `.Any()`

Comment: Equal `Day` values do not mean they are the same day (February 28 1905 has the same Day value as March 28 2020).

Comment: `var todaysSamples = db.SampleNIOSHTotalParticulate.Where(a => a.ProjectID == ProjectID && a.SampleDate.Date == DateTime.Today)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional condition in Where clause to check `SampleDate` like,

```
//Notice, I added additional condition in where clause
var FirstSampleOfTheDayCount = (from a in db.SampleNIOSHTotalParticulate
                           where a.ProjectID == ProjectID && a.SampleDate == DateTime.Today
                           select a).ToList().Count();

//Execute business logic if no record found
if(FirstSampleOfTheDayCount == 0)
{
  //Your business logic
}
```